# Dynamic Conditional Formatting to Pivot table ROWS

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have the following Pivot Table where I have monthly Electricity Consumption of each city in rows. I need to apply 3 color graded conditional formatting to "Values of each row, ie consumption of a city Month-on-Month".

[image: My Pivot Table]

When I tried to apply 3 color graded formatting to this pivot table, for Applies to section, pivot table is either considering selected cells or all values of pivot table but not only values of each row. This resulted my 3 color grading format spread across all the cities rather than each city separately.

I also have a filter in Pivot table with Country names.

My requirement is I need to apply the 3 color graded conditional formatting **separately to each city/row** dynamically so that when I change the country in filter any extra rows(cities) of that country should also get the formatting.

Comment: When you refresh a pivot table, does the conditional formatting stay intact or do you need to redefine it every time again?

Comment: It should stay intact. If USA has 50 cities, 3 color grade should be applied to eacj row/city Individually. When I change the country to India (which has 80 cities) the conditional formatting should be applied to the extra 30 rows also in the same row-by-row pattern